# How to Share the same Session id in Tomcat Cluster

Tags: tomcat, cluster-computing, sessionid

I have two tomcat instances running in Clustered Environment

Assume we have test.jsp is there in both Instances.

Suppose test.jsp is giving session ID(S1ID) in instance One,  how to get the same session ID(S2ID) from instance Two

Is this correct S1ID will be equal to S2ID??
Could you suggest how to configure tomcat cluster session replication. if they are equal (S1ID==S2ID)

Answer (score 0):

Session id saved in cookies,so if user access your domain using the same session id. You should keep the same id can get the same session from different tomcat.